# How to create a listView using arrayList?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

when I create this listview how do I assign a link to each of the meals that I create when I click on it. i should assign an identifier to each element but i tried and it doesn't work.

```
public class elencoPiatti extends AppCompatActivity {
    String link_pasta_lforno = "https://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Pasta-al-forno.html";
    String link_pesto = "https://www.oliocuore.it/prodotti/pesto-alla-genovese-cuore?gclid=Cj0KCQiA2uH-BRCCARIsAEeef3n5A7EWhBRBcaxSrGvMBijLuGX57p5hNu1nb4NG8Vhw_9C2qAfE6kUaAnbbEALw_wcB";
    String link_carbonara = "https://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Spaghetti-alla-Carbonara.html";

ListView listView;

String a = "pasta al forno";
String a1 = "carne";
String a2 = "sugo";
String a3 = "scamorza";
String  a4 ="0" ;

String b = "pesto";
String b1 = "pinoli";
String b2 = "pesto";
String b3 = "pepe";
String b4 = "1";

String r = "carbonara";
String r1 = "uova";
String r2 = "guanciale";
String r3 = "pecorino";
String r4 = "2";

String [][]c = {{"Nome piatto", "Alimento 1", "Alimento2", "Alimento3", "id"},
                {b, b1, b2, b3, b4},
                {a, a1, a2, a3, a4},
                {r, r1, r2, r3, r4}
                };




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.elenco);
//Prendo i paramtri in input
     Bundle primo_alimento=getIntent().getExtras();
     String primo= primo_alimento.getString("first");
     Bundle secondo_alimento=getIntent().getExtras();
     String secondo = secondo_alimento.getString("second");
     Bundle terzo_alimento=getIntent().getExtras() ;
     String terzo= terzo_alimento.getString("terzo");
//
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

int contatore =0;
for (int i = 1; i <4; i++) {

```
        for (int j = 1; j < 5 ; j++) {

               if (primo.equals(c[i][j]))
                    {
                 contatore++;
                             }
        if (secondo.equals(c[i][j]))
                            {
                             contatore++;
                            }
                        if (terzo.equals(c[i][j]))
                                {
                                contatore++;
                                 }

        }
                                if (contatore >=2){
                                    String numero = c[i][4];
                                    int intero = Integer.valueOf(numero);
                                    arrayList.add(intero,c[i][0]);
                                    contatore = 0;
                                    }



                                }

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (id==0){
                Intent aprilink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link_pasta_lforno));
                //Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),pastaalforno.class);

                startActivity(aprilink);

            }
            if (id==1){
                Intent aprilink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link_pesto));
                startActivity(aprilink);

            }
            if (id==2){
                Intent aprilink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link_carbonara));
                startActivity(aprilink);

            }

        }
    });
    }







}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

     // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, 
     // you already have yours).
     List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     your_array_list.add("foo");
     your_array_list.add("bar");

     // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
     // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
     // array as a third parameter.
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             your_array_list );

     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
}
}
```